# Spinnaker - Error during 'Create LoadBalancer'

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

I installed Spinnaker on my test cluster using Helm charts. When I tried to create a LoadBalancer, I noticed the 'namespace' dropdown was blank in the dialog box. When I just tried to create the loadbalancer, I see the error ' unregistered namespace'. I have attached screenshots for your reference. I would appreciate any help in resolving this! Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a test cluster using minikube or something like that?

Comment: This is a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster. I am sensing that this might  be an RBAC issue and Spinnaker does not have the necessary permissions.

Comment: I've got the same exactly problem using GKE. Any luck with that? I'm stuck :(

Comment: ping ... I'm stuck too

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, after some digging around, found that the cloudDriver was throwing bunch of error for access denied while accessing the kubernetes API's.

To see running pods: 
`kubectl get pods`

To see logs of the cloudDriver pods - `kubectl logs YOUR_CLOUD_DRIVER_POD_NAME`

I was reading online and found that spinnaker needs RBAC access control setup. Then lead me to this [answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/5483), which solved it for me temporarily until I get my self familiar with spinnaker.

Below command as suggested in above link, helped me and I was able to run spinnaker in minikube in my local machine.

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding spinnaker-default-crbinding --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:default`

Just to note that you will need to change --serviceaccount accordingly. I had to change it.